# add button navigationbar center

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

It is easy to add left and right buttonbaritem on navigationbar

but I hope to add button navigationbar center

my code is

```
 [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:button ];//button is not nil
```

but nothing happens

Yourc comment welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titleView` is `nil` by default so your code doesn't do anything.

Change the code to:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
```

This sets your button as the `titleView`.

Comment: the button added but why the button does not display

Comment: Update your question with the code used to create the button. Make sure it has a non-zero frame, it has a title, etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for UINavigationItem's titleView property, "Use the buttonWithType: method in UIButton class to add buttons to your custom view in the style of the navigation bar."